# Is it possible to add table prefixes for uuids in TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, uuid, typeorm

I have a lot of UUIDs in various places throughout my database, and the readability would be significantly improved if they contained a prefix to denote the type of entity they are for, such as `user-09a9c8fb-dcb6-5d18-9697-e1d10c552c14` or `comment-c80c8502-4cd9-483f-9b81-705a22dba3a8`. Is there any way to accomplish this purely with TypeORM syntax?

Here is an example of my current user model:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const generatePrefixedUUID = (prefix: string = ""): string => {
  return prefix + uuidv4().slice(prefix.length);
};
```

```
@PrimaryColumn({
  name: "id",
  unique: true,
})
id: string = generatePrefixedUUID("OR#");
```

This should be the simple solution.
Note: Use **PrimaryColumn** instead of **PrimaryGeneratedColumn**